# Me toma un elemento span como indefinido, cuando lo defini

Tags: javascript, array

Con mi codigo Javascript creo un array de elementos span. Sin embargo, cuando lo uso en la funcion me lo toma como indefinido en el navegador. No entiendo porque porque esta definido. Probe cambiando la forma de seleccionar (con getElementsById, con getElementsByTagName, etc) y no hubo caso todavia.

```
<h1 class="fancy">Juan de Tomaso</h1>
```

```
<script>
    const text = document.querySelector('.fancy');
    const strText = text.textContent;
    const splitText = strText.split("");
    text.textContent = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
        text.innerHTML += "<span>" + splitText[i] + "</span>";
    }

    let char = 0;
    let timer = setInterval(onTick, 40);

    function onTick() {
        let span = text.querySelectorAll('span');
        span[char].classList.add('fade');
        char++;
        if (char == splitText.lenght) {
            complete();
            return;
        }
    }

    function complete() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Y porqué usar un `setInterval()` para agregarle una clase a tus elementos? ¿Cuál es la idea detrás de este código?

Comment: Puede ser que de un error del selector al inicio del Javascript, en esta linea:const text = document.querySelector('.fancy');

Comment: La idea detras del codigo es que se "aparezca" el texto cada vez q se ejecuta setInterval.  Cada span tiene una letra, para eso es el "for" al principio. Es decir, cada 50ms se le agrega una class al span que hace que el texto aparezca. La class que le pongo al span tiene opacity:1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 3 errores:

1. Tienes un `typo` en tu condicional:

   splitText.lenght // <= mal

   splitText.length // <= correcto
2. Tu condicional apunta a un elemento único:

   if(char == splitText.length)

Deberías tenerlo:

```
if(char >= slpitText.length)
```

3. Tu condicional debe estar antes de cualquier operación en tu función `onTick()`.

```html
<h1 class="fancy">Juan de Tomaso</h1>

<script>
    const text = document.querySelector('.fancy');
    const strText = text.textContent;
    const splitText = strText.split("");
    text.textContent = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
        text.innerHTML += "<span>" + splitText[i] + "</span>";
    }

    let char = 0;
    let timer = setInterval(onTick, 40);

    function onTick() {
        console.log(char);
        if (char >= splitText.length) {
            complete();
            return;
        }
        let span = text.querySelectorAll('span');
        span[char].classList.add('fade');
        char++;
    }

    function complete() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
</script>
```

¿La razón de los pasos 2 y 3?

Es que de esta forma evitas que el código avance o evalúe una condición no válida, y dado que el mismo está en la cola de eventos, no hay garantía de que el llamado a `clearInterval` se ejecute en el momento inmediato a su llamada.

Por lo tanto, `char` puede tener un valor superior a la cantidad de elementos que hay en tu iterable y de allí el mensaje de error: `span[char] is undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Te sale indefinido porque llega un momento en que la función que llamas con `setInterval()` deja de encontrar elementos `<span>` dentro de la colección que iteras para ponerles la clase *fade*.

¿Y por qué pasa esto? Porque la condición de salida que tienes puesta jamás se cumple, por lo que la función del intervalo se sigue ejecutando hasta comenzar a buscar índices inexistentes dentro de la colección.

Todo viene por un sencillo pero mortal error tipográfico.

Escribiste **lenght** en vez de **length**:

```
if (char == splitText.lenght) {
  complete();
  return;
}
```

**Código funcionando:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="fancy">Juan de Tomaso</h1>
<script>
    const text = document.querySelector('.fancy');
    const strText = text.textContent;
    const splitText = strText.split("");
    text.textContent = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
        text.innerHTML += "<span>" + splitText[i] + "</span>";
    }

    let char = 0;
    let timer = setInterval(onTick, 40);

    function onTick() {
        let span = text.querySelectorAll('span');
        span[char].classList.add('fade');
        char++;
        if (char == splitText.length) {
            complete();
            return;
        }
    }

    function complete() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: jajajaja mortal, soy un tarado. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

intentas que segun tu array se multiplique span? intena con text.append(" mi codigo"); dentro del for de javascript  o  dame cualquier otra forma de ayudarte

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\JavaScript Projects\animatedhead1\style.css">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
    <title>Fancy</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <h1 class="fancy">Juan de Tomaso</h1>
    <a id="ejemplo">append</a>



    <!--Here goes my Javascript-->



    <script>
  
for(let i=0;i<40;i++){
  $("#ejemplo").append("<span>Juan de Tomaso</span>"); 
}
 
 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

el código aquí
    introducir el código aquí

Comment: me parece que el problema es mas por -> libreria :  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Gracias Daimer. La idea detras del codigo es que se "aparezca" el texto cada vez q se ejecuta setInterval. Es decir, cada 50ms se le agrega una class al span que hace que el texto aparezca. La class que le pongo al span tiene opacity:1. Eso hace el efecto de aparicion

Comment: Por eso genero un elemento span que contiene cada letra del texto, y a cada span se le agrega la clase luego